# Retrieve records from Sqlserver db with VB .net

Tags: .net, sql-server, vb.net, ado.net

Here is what I'm working with:

```
Dim connstr = "data source=mydatasource;initial catalog=gcs_dw;persist security   info=True;user id=myuser;password=mypassword;Asynchronous Processing=True"
Dim sqlquery = "SELECT * FROM Customer WHERE CITY = 'Anytown'"
Dim connection As SqlConnection = New SqlConnection(connstr)
connection.Open()

Dim command As SqlCommand = connection.CreateCommand()
command.CommandText = sqlquery
Dim reader As SqlDataReader = command.ExecuteReader()
reader.Read()
Console.WriteLine(reader.ToString)
connection.Close()
Console.Read()
```

As you can see, I'm attempting to display the results of the query to the commandline and currently all it is displaying is "System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader". Where are the results of my sql query going and why can't I retrieve them?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is the problem:

```
Console.WriteLine(reader.ToString)
```

You're calling `ToString` directly on the reader, rather than asking it for a specific value from the current row. Something like:

```
Console.WriteLine(reader.GetString(0))
```

should be fine.

Comment: I knew that .ToString was doing exactly what it was suppose it, I simply didn't know what else to use. Both .GetString and .GetValue worked perfectly. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
Dim str As String

Dim myConn As SqlConnection = New SqlConnection("Server=(local)\netsdk;" & _
                                                "uid=sa;pwd=;database=master")

str = "CREATE DATABASE MyDatabase ON PRIMARY " & _
      "(NAME = MyDatabase_Data, " & _
      " FILENAME = 'D:\MyFolder\MyDatabaseData.mdf', " & _
      " SIZE = 2MB, " & _
      " MAXSIZE = 10MB, " & _
      " FILEGROWTH = 10%) " & _
      " LOG ON " & _
      "(NAME = MyDatabase_Log, " & _
      " FILENAME = 'D:\MyFolder\MyDatabaseLog.ldf', " & _
      " SIZE = 1MB, " & _
      " MAXSIZE = 5MB, " & _
      " FILEGROWTH = 10%) "

Dim myCommand As SqlCommand = New SqlCommand(str, myConn)

Try
    myConn.Open()
    myCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
    MessageBox.Show("Database is created successfully", _
                    "MyProgram", MessageBoxButtons.OK, _
                     MessageBoxIcon.Information)
   Catch ex As Exception
       MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString())
   Finally
       If (myConn.State = ConnectionState.Open) Then
           myConn.Close()
       End If
   End Try
```

End Sub